# How to Close SSIS Connection with RetainSameConnection = True

Tags: ssis, connection

I have an ODBC connection with RetainSameConnection set to True.

I think it is remaining open after my package completes, because simple queries like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable` directly from my query browser hang.

Does this sound likely?  How can I prove / disprove my theory?  Is there a way to force this connection to close in SSIS after I've finished with it?

Comment: I think there is problem with connection not closing.. I tried to see open connections after executing package and it showed an open connection.. need to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disproved my theory by doing a `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable` which successfully returned instantly.

Weirdly, the problem was the `COUNT(*)` was actually really slow - when I added some clauses (that affect no records) the count returned instantly.  The clauses changed the query execution plan so that the primary key is used.  Not sure why it wouldn't use the key anyway...

```
-- Slooooow - 500K records
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable

-- Instant - 500K records
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE ColX > 0 AND ColY > 0
```

Comment: The first is probably resulting in a table scan which means SQL Server needs to read all the pages in off disk for that table to get the answer. The second is probably allowing SQL Server to take advantage of an index which is typically much more narrow resulting in fewer IO requests, etc, etc.